# How to set the right axis range for plt.pcolor() in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I want to plot the heat map of a pivoted data frame

```
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns 
%matplotlib inline

sample = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'x': np.tile(np.arange(2,5),(1,5))[0],
                                            'y': np.tile(np.arange(0,5),(1,3))[0],
                                            'value': np.random.rand(15)
                                            }) 
sample_pvt = sample.pivot_table(index='x',columns='y')  
plt.pcolor(sample_pvt)
```

Even though x range from 2 to 5, the plot only shows 0 to 3 range. I know using seaborn can solve the issue, but is there a way to specify the axis range in pcolor? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seaborn would simply annotate the rows and columns of the pcolor(mesh) plot. To achieve the same here,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

sample = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'x': np.tile(np.arange(2,5),(1,5))[0],
                                            'y': np.tile(np.arange(0,5),(1,3))[0],
                                            'value': np.random.rand(15)
                                            }) 
sample_pvt = sample.pivot_table(index='x',columns='y')  
sample_pvt.columns = sample_pvt.columns.droplevel(0)


plt.pcolor(sample_pvt)
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(sample_pvt.columns))+0.5,  sample_pvt.columns)
plt.yticks(np.arange(len(sample_pvt.index))+0.5,  sample_pvt.index)

plt.show()
```

[image]

To instead place the pixels in the numerically correct way, you need to first decide if the x and y values are actually the centers or the edges of the pixels. For the centers,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)

sample = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'x': np.tile(np.arange(2,5),(1,5))[0],
                                            'y': np.tile(np.arange(0,5),(1,3))[0],
                                            'value': np.random.rand(15)
                                            }) 
sample_pvt = sample.pivot_table(index='x',columns='y')  
sample_pvt.columns = sample_pvt.columns.droplevel(0)

x = np.linspace(sample_pvt.columns[0]-0.5, sample_pvt.columns[-1]+0.5, len(sample_pvt.columns)+1)
y = np.linspace(sample_pvt.index[0]-0.5, sample_pvt.index[-1]+0.5, len(sample_pvt.index)+1)
plt.pcolor(x, y, sample_pvt)

plt.show()
```

[image]

For the edges,

```
x = np.linspace(sample_pvt.columns[0], sample_pvt.columns[-1]+1, len(sample_pvt.columns)+1)
y = np.linspace(sample_pvt.index[0], sample_pvt.index[-1]+1, len(sample_pvt.index)+1)
plt.pcolor(x, y, sample_pvt)
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way to make y axis start from 0 instead of 2? I tried  plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 5, 1)) but blank showed up at the wrong end of the blocks and 0-3 are now colored where 4-5 are not